# incrementBy not working, Set auto_increment_offset as global variable for mariadb liquibase

Tags: database, mariadb, liquibase

Following syntax is giving validation error when we run liquibase migration.

```
 <addAutoIncrement columnDataType="int"
                          columnName="intColumn"
                          generationType="ALWAYS"
                          incrementBy="2"
                          startWith="100"
                          tableName="autoincrement_test"/>
```

As per this link https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/2863 in latest liquibase version they are throwing validation error for incrementby usage.
Liquibase is suggesting to set a global variable for `auto_increment_offset`.
Can someone suggest how can I set this value using liquibase?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you share the exact text of the validation error?

Comment: I think a mariadb fix for liquidbase would be to use [sequences](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequences/) to implement `incrementBy` rather than `AUTO INCREMENT`. The linked fix to the issue in description says "mysql /mariadb - Neither support specifying incrementBy, so that is now a validation error.".